# Pourquoi ces deux phrases sont problématiques ? "On se demande c'est à quoi ça leur a servi" et "J'écoute, mais je tiens pas compte"

Tags: grammaire

Dans cet [entretien](https://www.lexpress.fr/culture/livre/claude-hagege-imposer-sa-langue-c-est-imposer-sa-pensee_1098440.html), le journaliste a cité ces deux phrases de Nicolas Sarkozy en parlant des fautes linguistiques commises par un chef d'Etat.

> Nicolas Sarkozy est coutumier des fautes de syntaxe : "On se demande c'est à quoi ça leur a servi..." ou encore "J'écoute, mais je tiens pas compte". Est-ce grave, de la part d'un chef d'Etat?

Mais, en tant qu'élève de la langue française, je ne comprends pas trop pourquoi elles sont problématiques. Quelle est la bonne façon de formuler ces phrases ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans *On se demande c'est à quoi ça leur a servi...*, on peut trouver deux usages familiers:

- *c'est quoi* (ou avec une préposition : *c'est à quoi*, *c'est pour quoi*, etc) utilisé à la place de *ce que* (ou avec un préposition *ce pour quoi* ou *ce à quoi*, ou *pour quoi* ou *à quoi*)
- *ça* au lieu de *cela*

Il aurait donc mieux valu que Sarkozy dise: "on se demande à quoi cela leur a servi".

Dans *j'écoute mais je tiens pas compte*, le "ne" a été omis, ce qui est extrêmement courant en français parlé. On aurait alors dit "je ne tiens pas compte".
On pourrait aussi estimer qu'il faudrait ajouter un pronom "en" ("je n'*en* tiens pas compte"), mais cela ne me semble pas une faute: *je ne tiens pas compte* est une affirmation plus générale.

Utiliser *ça* pour *cela* et omettre le *ne* sont très courants en français parlé. Cela déplait sans doute à certains dans une bouche présidentielle, qui attendent d'un président qu'il s'exprime toujours dans un français formel, mais on ne peut pas considérer cela comme des fautes.

*C'est à quoi* sera sans doute moins accepté, même dans le français parlé: c'est le genre de syntaxe que des enfants utilisent, et que leurs professeurs corrigent, même à l'oral.

Comment: Il me semble que "tenir compte" et "prendre en compte" sont tous les deux transitifs, donc il aurait bien dû dire "j'écoute mais je n'en tiens pas compte" ou "je ne tiens pas compte de cela".
C'est sûrement un abus de langage un peu familier mais si je devais choisir une formule pour l'utiliser sans complément, je choisirais "prendre en compte" : "j'écoute mais je ne prends pas en compte". Cette formulation me semble plus naturelle.

Comment: Merci pour vos explications !

Comment: Sa manière de parler est très proche de « on se demande (c'est) à quoi que ça leur a servi » qui est très très oralisant chez moi. Ouais la transitivité fait que je dirais « je ne tiens pas compte de (ça) » dans ce genre de registre. C'est une comparaison régionale.